# Salesforce1 auto populate Contact address from Account?

Tags: salesforce1-app, automation

It's been a couple of years since I've dug into Salesforce and I can't seem to find the answer here - apologies if this is a re-ask.

In our setup if I go through the Web interface, when a Contact is created either by clicking on 'Accounts >> (Select Account) >> New Contact' or by clicking  'Contacts >> New >> 'populate Account field'' the address is automatically filled into the Contact record.

However, when we create Contacts via the Salesforce1 app this functionality is not carried over.

Does anyone know how I can do this declaratively?

Comment: you could use process builder to detect on new Contact if `mailingXXX` = null  to fetch from parent `Account.Billingxxx` field where `xxx` = `Country`, `City`, `Street`, etc.

Comment: @cropredy, thanks for this tip - I tested this in Sandbox (it worked) and have now created it in the Production db but when I create a contact in the Salesforce1 app since building this it does not show up.  The new contact shows up on the desktop site, but not in the app.  Any ideas why this is?

Comment: this would be a new question; I'll post my comment as an Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to:

1. Use process builder on new Contact
2. If value of Contact field `MailingXXX` is null, then use immediate actions to set value from parent `Account.BillingXXX`

where XXX is `Street`, `City`, `State`, `Country`, and `PostalCode`